# Google Maps API check if a location has weather information

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, weather, google-weather-api

In Google Maps API v3 is it possible checking if weather data is available for a specified location?
I mean the weather icon, clicking on which the tooltip popups showing forecasts for the next days.

**<EDIT>**
I am using the WeatherLayer and the CloudLayer integrated in the Google Maps API v3.
**</EDIT>**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this with weather library. The WeatherLayer and CloudLayer objects allow you to add weather forecasts and cloud imagery to your map.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#WeatherLayer

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify that I am already using the WeatherLayer and the CloudLayer available in the GMaps API v3. Therefore you suggest to add a listener of the click event on the weather layer, is it right? It would be perfect if I could know a location has a weather layer notwithstanding the user interaction with it.